# "I recall" or "I recalled"

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

When trying to remember or talking about a past event at present, should it be in past or present tense?

For e.g.

> I recall having a conversation about the flight bookings.
> I recalled having a conversation about the flight bookings.

Should "recall" or "recalled" be used in the above examples?

Comment: If you recalled something, it was not right now.

Answer (score 2):

> When trying to remember or talking about a past event **at present**, should it be in past or present tense?

We use the present tense *"recall"* if you are doing the action **at present**.

Comment: talking about a past event in the  present; at present means now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is **recall**. You are currently remembering something that happened. *Recall* is present, so that is the verb tense that should be used. Hope this helps!

Jackie L